# How to make linked list with localy declared head?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list, double-pointer, function-definition

I need to make a program which connects two linked lists before I used global pointer for the head of the list, but now I need to make it locally so I can insert new element(node) to each of them, but I have a problem with double-pointer, not sure when to use **, when * and when &. I can find any example similar to that.
Down below is what I have now.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct element_{
    int x;
    struct element_ *next;
}element;


void insert(element **head, int x) {
    element *new_ = new element;
    element *p;
    new_->x = x;
    new_->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        *head = new_;
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (p = *head;p->next != NULL;p = p->next) {}
        p->next = new_;
    }

}


int main(){
    element **head = NULL;

    insert(head,1);
    insert(head,3);
    insert(head,3);
    insert(head,4);

    for (element *p = *head;p != NULL;p = p->next){
        printf("%d ", p->x);
    }


}
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be C++ or C? You tag says C++ but clearly your code says C (except for that `new`).

Comment: Yes, there are several fundamental problems, regarding confusion between single and double pointers, in the shown code. The best thing you can do is keep plugging away at your textbook, trying to learn and understand what pointers are, how they work, what a double-pointer means, and all related fundamental concepts. The best way to learn and understand these concepts is to keep reading, and rereading, until you understand it. Trying to randomly use `*`, `**`, and `&`, until the code compiles, is unlikely to produce meaningful results.

Comment: Actually wanted to give a hint in an answer; yet it seems - as @Sam Varshavchik writes, that you are coding by trial and error; Explaining the concepts in an answer takes rather long; textbooks about C algorithms and data structures do a better job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing from C++ in the program except the operator `new`. So if to substitute the operator new for a call of `malloc` then you will get a pure C program.

So a C looking function `insert` can be defined like

```
void insert(element **head, int x) 
{
    element *new_ = new element;

    new_->x = x;
    new_->next = NULL;

    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    *head = new_;
}
```

And in main you should write

```
element *head = NULL;

insert( &head, 1 );
insert( &head, 3 );
insert( &head, 3 );
insert( &head, 4 );

for (element *p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next )
{
    printf("%d ", p->x);
}
```

Something that looks like a C++ function `insert` can be defined the following way

```
void insert( element * &head, int x ) 
{
    element *new_ = new element { x, nullptr };

    element **current = &head;

    while ( *current != NULL )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    *current = new_;
}
```

And in main you should write

```
element *head = nullptr;

insert( head, 1 );
insert( head, 3 );
insert( head, 3 );
insert( head, 4 );

for (element *p = head; p != nullptr; p = p->next )
{
    std::cout << p->x << ' ';
}
```

But to call the program indeed as C++ program then you should define the list as a class. Moreover if new nodes are appended to the tail of the singly-linked list then you should define the list a singly-linked two-sided list.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class List
{
private:    
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *next;
    } *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;

public:
    List() = default;
    List( const List & ) = delete;
    List & operator =( const List & ) = delete;
    ~List()
    {
        clear();
    }

    void clear()
    {
        while ( head )
        {
            delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
        }

        tail = head;
    }

    void  push_front( int data ) 
    {
        head = new Node { data, head };
        if ( !tail ) tail = head;
    }       

    void  push_back( int data ) 
    {
        Node *node = new Node { data, nullptr };

        if ( tail )
        {
            tail = tail->next = node;
        }
        else
        {
            head = tail = node;
        }
    }       

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const List &list )
    {
        for ( Node *current = list.head; current; current = current->next )
        {
            std::cout << current->data << " -> ";
        }

        return std::cout << "null";
    }
};


int main()
{
    List list;

    list.push_back( 1 );
    list.push_back( 3 );
    list.push_back( 3 );
    list.push_back( 4 );

    std::cout << list << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
1 -> 3 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nearly correct C code.

If `head` in `main` is a pointer to a pointer to `element` you have to dynamically allocate memory for it. It makes the code unnecessary complex. I made `head` in `main` a pointer to `element`. But you want to change it's value in `insert` so you have to pass by reference. The C way of pass by value is to pass the address. Also there is no `new` in C. Use `malloc`. And remember to clean up at the end. You have to call one `free` for each `malloc`.

If it really is supposed to be C++ code you have much to do. E.g, you wouldn't use pointers to pointers but references, you would use smart pointers instead of dynamic memory allocation, ...

Even though this is not the C++ way of programming it's also valid C++ code (I'm not sure about the headers).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element_{
    int x;
    struct element_ *next;
} element;

void insert(element **head, int x) {
    element *new_ = malloc(sizeof(element));
    element *p;
    new_->x = x;
    new_->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = new_;
        return;
    } else {
        for (p = *head;p->next != NULL;p = p->next) {}
        p->next = new_;
    }
}

void clean(element **p) {
    if ((*p)->next != NULL) clean(&(*p)->next);
    free(*p);
    *p = NULL;
}

int main(){
    element *head = NULL;

    insert(&head, 1);
    insert(&head, 3);
    insert(&head, 3);
    insert(&head, 4);

    for (element *p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next){
        printf("%d ", p->x);
    }

    clean(&head);
}
```